# Sonatype Nexus search api is very slow because of small page size

Tags: nexus, sonatype, nexus3

I have a code which keep fetch the following page until the continuation token is null. It's very slow because each call only return 50 items and there are many pages.

```
http://<<nexus-host>>/service/rest/v1/search/assets?repository=docker-registry&name=xyz/*&format=docker
```

Is it a way to increase the page size? The document doesn't show anything about page size:
https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/search-api

Or how to fetch the pages concurrently? Each consequential call needs the continuation token from the previous call....

Comment: Unfortunately there is not (yet ?.....) any option to change the page size in the pagination strategy. There is an [opened ticket for this](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-21074) as well as a [proposed PR](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/pull/51)